# facing an alert of error on Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

[image]**Error showing on all woocommerce shop page and single product page After theme update and al the plugins updates.**

```
Sorry, no products matched your selection. Please choose a different combination.
```

Comment: Try deactivating the plugins one by one and see if its a particular plugin is causing the error message. If you can provide the website link, I might be able to take a look at it.

Comment: Thank you, Akhilesh for a reply. But I tried but nothing work and the problem the same.

Comment: Try looking at the source of your webpage and search for the above text(or in javascript files). If you are able to find it, you will be able to know where/what exactly is throwing that alert message! Also, look at developer console(in webbrowser) to see if its showing any hints(or errors).

Comment: Thanks Akhilesh but not able to inspect the element. It unable to do right click.

Comment: Most probably a javascript code is there that voids the right click. Maybe that's the reason why you are not able to right-click. Anyway, if you are using Google Chrome, press `Ctrl+Shift+I` This will open up the Inspector window.

Comment: yes may be but finally problem fixed by remove and add again attribute in variable product. Thank you so much Akhilesh for your support and comments. Issue solved.

Comment: Glad to hear that its resolved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Main problem coming from 3-4 products and finally we found one by one and it was attribute issue. So first remove the attribute and added again. Now the site is fine.
I found this answer from below link:
https://wpgarage.com/plugins/solution-to-woocommerce-error-sorry-no-products-matched-your-selection-please-choose-a-different-combination/

Thank you for your comment and support who respond on this question.

Answer (score 0):

```
function woo_custom_ajax_variation_threshold( $qty, $product ) {
        return 50;
    }       
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_ajax_variation_threshold', 'woo_custom_ajax_variation_threshold', 10, 2 );
```

Try increasing alowed variations